# iTextSharp Object Initializer

Tags: itext

I am using the iTextSharp library to do my reports on ASP.NET and C#.
I've used it before on other solutions but this particular one has issues.

The error reads thus:

> Feature 'object initializer' cannot be used because it is not part of
>   the ISO-2 C# language specification

This occurs on every line I try to initialize a new object, e.g:

```
PdfPCell cellMembeNo = new PdfPCell(
    new Phrase("Member No:",  tableTd_Header)) { BorderWidthRight = 0f };
```

I tried targeting my solution to .NET version 4.0 but got an error

```
Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'.
```

Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
PdfPCell cellMembeNo = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Member No:",  tableTd_Header));
cellMembeNo.BorderWidthRight = 0f;
```

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks, that works as I had also tried that but there are alot of lines of code with the previous parameter initialization which has always worked save from this particular solution am working on....it's a legacy system developed ages ago and I thought there's a way of bringing it up to current frameworks, didn't work....my guess is that the framework has issues and I should probably rephrase my question to how best can I re-assign the target framework and if there's anything I need to add...